# Objective-C issue with Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have this Segue here:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        //NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
        NSString *strPOIndex = [self.tableData[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"POIndex"];
        LHPurchaseOrderDetail *controller = (LHPurchaseOrderDetail *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
        [controller setDetailItem:strPOIndex];
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
    }
}
```

and what I am trying to do with it is pass strPOIndex to setDetailItem in my detail controller from my master controller.. but when I run this, I get an error:

```
-[LHPurchaseOrderMaster setDetailItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x156cce80
```

I dont understand why this is happening, is it an issue with my storyboard? or my master controller or detail controller? Here is my Detail Controller:

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LHPurchaseOrderDetail : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *NavBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "LHPurchaseOrderDetail.h"

@interface LHPurchaseOrderDetail ()

@end

@implementation LHPurchaseOrderDetail

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


@end
```

Master Controller:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ShinobiDataSource.h"
#import "PopupGenerator.h"

@class LHPurchaseOrderDetail;

@interface LHPurchaseOrderMaster : UITableViewController<UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *communityBtn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *lotBtn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *goBtn;


- (IBAction)communityBtnPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)lotBtnPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)goBtnPressed:(id)sender;

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray * tableData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) LHPurchaseOrderDetail *purchaseOrderController;


@end
```

Comment: are you sure that the topViewController is of LHPurchaseOrderDetail type? try debugging the line and see what is the real type being returned

Comment: Have you tried just using ` LHPurchaseOrderDetail *controller = (LHPurchaseOrderDetail *)[segue destinationViewController];`!? Why would you access the `topViewController` property?

Comment: @luk2302 I guess he's accessing the `topViewController` property because his UIViewController is embedded in an UINavigationController and the segue is to that navigationController (hence the cast).

Comment: So many shots in the dark!   `NSLog(@"destination vc %@", [segue destinationViewController]);`  then  `NSLog(@"destination vc %@", [[segue destinationViewController] topViewController]);`  Post that result here.  The code is clearly taking a risk by casting the result of destinationVC expression to something that it apparently isn't.

Comment: @danh if everybody would just start logging and debugging before crying for help, that would be so much easier...

Answer (score 0):

Your error is this:

```
-[LHPurchaseOrderMaster setDetailItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x156cce80
```

so it seems that somewhere in your `LHPurchaseOrderMaster` class you're trying to access and set the `detailItem` property as if it would be a part of `LHPurchaseOrderMaster` but because it doesn't exist there, you get an `unrecognized selector` error.

**Edit**

You should check for three things:

1. In `Interface Builder` check that the segue from `LHPurchaseOrderMaster` ViewController is to an `UINavigationController` that embeds the `LHPurchaseOrderDetail` ViewController as the first view controller in its stack.
2. Check the Class name returned by `[segue destinationViewController]topViewController]` like this:

   `id obj = [segue destinationViewController]topViewController];
   NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([obj class]));`

The class name should be `LHPurchaseOrderDetail`. If it's not, then you have a problem in your Storyboard where more than certainly you've connected the segue wrong.

3. Check your `LHPurchaseOrderMaster` class for any code that tries to access the "detailItem" property as if it would be part of this class.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the property you are trying to access is not accessible (wrong retrieved object).

Have you tried to use instead of

```
LHPurchaseOrderDetail *controller = (LHPurchaseOrderDetail *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
```

Something like

```
LHPurchaseOrderDetail *controller = (LHPurchaseOrderDetail *)[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers][0];
```

I had sometimes the same your issue.

Comment: No, if it was not accessible a different error would occur!

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't express correctly. For "not accessible" i mean an object that doesn't have that property or method. This happens when you try to call a method in a object that doesn't have that method.

Comment: Okay, that is true for sure, but it does not really help with the problem (i am btw not the one who down voted you.)

Comment: Sometimes I just fixed the problem with that method. I was just trying to help. :)

Answer (score -1):

Set your `detailItem` not to `NSString`. Not to id. The problem is here,

```
self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
```

In `configureView` method change the code as follow,

```
- (void)configureView {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = self.detailItem;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to change this as well,

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(NSString *)newDetailItem {
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}
```